# How i can use global properties in custom variables? (SASS)

Tags: css, angular, sass

I'm trying to initialize a variable from custom properties but I can't access it from another file.
More specifically I have set in my _breakpointes-variables.scss

```
: root {
    //Main breakpoints variables
    --mobile: 30em;
    --tablet: 64em;
    --sm-screen: 82em;
    --m-screen: 120em;
    --l-screen: 140em;
    --xl-screen: 160em;
}
```

And in my _breakpointes.scss i want something like this

```
$breakpoints: (
    "mobile": 30em,
    "tablet": 64em,
    "sm-screen": 82em,
    "m-screen": 120em,
    "l-screen": 140em,
    "xl-screen": 160em,
) !default;
```

I already tried with var(--mobile) but I can't get the value in $breakpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mobile: 30em;
$tablet: 64em;
$sm-screen: 82em;
$m-screen: 120em;
$l-screen: 140em;
$xl-screen: 160em;
:root {
    //Main breakpoints variables
    --mobile: #{$mobile};
    --tablet: #{$tablet};
    --sm-screen: #{$sm-screen};
    --m-screen: #{$m-screen};
    --l-screen: #{$l-screen};
    --xl-screen: #{$xl-screen};
}
```